# Why String.match() method returns multiple values?

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I've got the following string, defined in my Javascript code:

```
var s = "10px solid #101010";
```

Now, I want to get only the numeric initial part. For this purporse, I tried the following:

```
s.match(/^([0-9]+)/g);
```

It works like a charm, and the result was `['10']`.

After this test, I also tried to remove the `g` modifier, as follows:

```
s.match(/^([0-9]+)/);
```

I expected the same result, but I was wrong. The result is an array with two solutions: `['10', '10']`.

Can someone explain me why? What is the meaning of the last element of the array, in the second case?

Comment: Good question, which actually already has a really good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577704/why-capturing-group-results-in-double-matches-regex

Comment: ^^ The accepted answer actually does have a very good explanation of this, seems like a duplicate.

Comment: If I have not clear the concept of "capturing group", the answer of question you quote is not adequate (in my opinion)...

Comment: @VitoShadow I guess you actually wanted to put the `+` into the capturing group like `/^([0-9]+)/` otherwise the group would only capture single digits

Comment: Also ... the result of removing `g` is `['10', '0']` rather than `['10', '10']` ... at least in my Chrome

Comment: just get rid of the brackets ;-) ... `s.match(/^[0-9]+/g);` works like your first example and `s.match(/^[0-9]+/);` doesn't give the duplicate ... you don't even need to specify the start (`^`), as it's the first match `s.match(/[0-9]+/);` ... and if you like, you could use `\d` instead of [0-9] `s.match(/\d+/);`

Answer (score -2):

'/g' returns all matched ones, It wont stop at first matching point

'g '-   Perform a global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp