# Html, A tag using onclick functionatity for redirection

Tags: html, tags

```
<a href='#' onclick='returnUrl = /url=(https?:\/\/.+)/.exec(location); if(returnUrl)location.href = returnUrl[1];else location.href = "/"'>Back to Blog</a>
```

Can anyone explain the above code in detail?

Comment: This is a good opportunity to move your code into a function and split up each operation to its own line.  Then use your browser's debugging tools to step through the code as it executes and examine the result of each operation.  When you do this, which operation is unclear?  Which operation produces a result you didn't expect?

Comment: I don't understand html.. could you kindly explain the working of the code written inside onclick?

Comment: (1) The specific code you're asking about is JavaScript, not HTML.  (2) If you don't understand HTML or JavaScript then your first step would be to find some introductory tutorials on those technologies and start learning.  Stack Overflow can help with specific problems in your code, but we don't provide custom tutoring services to teach you these technologies.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: i have been spending the last 4 hours trying to breakdown the working of this code.and i understand that onclicking the link it redirects to the home page and exec function is used to identify the pattern inside location parameter. But i couldn't find returnUrl parameter anywhere in the website i was looking at. I also didnt find why that url http thing is put between "/ /".

Comment: In the code you're showing `returnUrl` is called a "variable".  Variables are used to store values in code.  Since it has an implicit declaration, it's by default a property on the `window` object.  And the syntax between the forward slashes is called a "regular expression".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example:

1. you trying to apply regex `url=(https?:\/\/.+)` to current location, afaik "location" can't return something starts with "url=", but i can mistake.
2. regex.exec answer (it's Array) you insert in returnUrl var
3. if there is some entries in given array, then you insert second entry in location.href (why second?: [Why capturing group results in double matches regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577704/why-capturing-group-results-in-double-matches-regex))
4. if there is no entries in given array, then you insert '/' in location.href

inserting a value into a 'location' variable is equivalent for navigating to inserted url

regex explanation from regex.com

```
url= matches the characters url= literally (case sensitive)
1st Capturing Group (https?:\/\/.+)
http matches the characters http literally (case sensitive)
s?
matches the character s literally (case sensitive)
: matches the character : literally (case sensitive)
\/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
\/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
.+
matches any character (except for line terminators)
```

your example in pseudocode:

```
if there is matches for /url=(https?:\/\/.+)/ in location
then redirect to this match (in group)
else redirect to '/'
```