# Why are characters outside my capturing parentheses included in matches from my RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex

Working in JavaScript I have strings that might contain words prefixed by an "@". The string might look like this `@one two @three`. I want a RegExp that finds the words prefixed by the "@" but I don't want to include the "@" itself.

I created a RegExp looking like this `/@(\w+)/g` but when I match it against my strings the "@" is indeed included. Why is this? I assumed that if I wanted to include it then the "@" would be inside the capturing parentheses like this `/(@\w+)/g`

```
var s = '@one two @three'
var matches = s.match(/@(\w+)/g)
// matches is now [ '@one', '@three' ] but I want [ 'one', 'three' ]
```

**Note** with the result I currently get, there is of course no problem in getting the array I want, I can just remove the first character of each string. But what I want to know is:

Is it possible to change my RegExp to get the desired result?
And:
Why are characters outside my capturing parenthesis included in the result? I find it intuitive that only the characters inside the parenthesis should be included.

Comment: I don't think this question is really a duplicate of the one it's marked as being a duplicate of, but that in turn is because OP has the wrong understanding of the problem. In short, there is nothing wrong with the regex, but the problem is that `match()` doesn't return captured groups if the `g` flag is present. If `g` is not present it does, but then you only get the first match. What you see in `matches` are all full matches of your regex, of which the @ characters are part. A "positive lookbehind" could have fixed this I think but javascript doesn't support that.

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg If you write this post as an answer and perhaps confirm that there is also no other regexp method that would solve this then I will confirm that as the accepted answer since this is the type of information I am looking for,

Comment: I actually intended to make that an answer but it seems you can't add answers now that the question has been marked as duplicate.

Comment: @Witkor The correct (or at least primary) duplicate for this question should be `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901334/i-cant-accurately-understand-how-does-javascripts-method-string-matchregexp`. Would you please update the linked-to duplicate box? That way I can flag the previous comments for removal as no longer required. (This question came up in the Reopen Queue and I'm trying to stop that from happening again.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to access first capturing group

```
var re = /@(\w+)/gm; 
var str = '@one two @three';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    print(m[1]);
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/NcWkgf)**

*JS Demo*

```js
var re = /@(\w+)/; 
var arr = ['@one', 'two', '@three'];

arr.forEach(function(str) {
  if (str.match(re))
  document.writeln(str.match(re)[1] + '<br>');
});
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Actually I directly imported the code from regex101..

Comment: While this is a solution on how to arrive at the result I want, I do not find it to be an answer to my question. I have clarified it some.

Comment: @LudwigMagnusson do you want to know the reason for why is that happening in your code?

Comment: I want an explanation for why the match function returns what it does and an answer to if it is possible to get what I want by changing the regexp alone. Peter Hedenborg basically explained it in his comment to my question.

Comment: @LudwigMagnusson see **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901334/i-cant-accurately-understand-how-does-javascripts-method-string-matchregexp)** about how match works in JS